# How to design a filter with a certain magnitude response

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to design a filter whose magnitude is the same as that of a given signal. The given signal is wind turbine noise, so it has significant low-frequency content. After designing the filter, I want to filter white Gaussian noise so as to create a model of wind turbine noise. The two signals, that is the original and the filtered noise should sound similar.

I am using arbitrary magnitude filter design in Matlab for that (FIR, Order: 900, Single rate, 1-band, response specified by amplitudes, Sample rate 44100 Hz, Design method: firls). The problem is that, although I design the filter using the values from the original signal's magnitude, the filter magnitude fails to follow the magnitude at higher frequencies. Could you please help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for frequency domain filtering - use an FFT-based method such as overlap-add or overlap-save to filter your Gaussian noise.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution may be to increase the filter order. Your filter design function may also allow you to specify a weighting function that will let you specify where the filter should have a tighter fit to the specifications. You might also ask this question on http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think that n = 900 is already high enough for my computer. I will try also the weighting function. Thank you! I ve also posted this to  dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In terms of Fir filters, 900 isnt really all that high. An analog filter might do better, if you have any experience with signal processing (4th order chebbychev for instance)

Comment: @Mauvai: The problem is that as the order rises the filter lobes create an unwanted effect when I play the sound. You can see the desired response in red and the designed filter in blue (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43013925/filter%20response.png)